# Accessing global label in function using pathname in Tk

Tags: label, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am using following code to change text of a label from within a function. For this I have to use a variable name for a label.

```
#! /usr/bin/wish8.6

set mylabel [label .a_lab -text "INITIAL TEXT"]
button .a_button -text "Change"     -command changer
pack .a_lab -fill both -expand 1
pack .a_button -fill both -expand 1

proc changer {} {
    # $::mylabel config -text "changed!";# works; 
    $::.a_lab config -text "NEW TEXT!"    ;# does not work; 
    }

wm geometry . 300x200+300+300
```

Can I not use only its pathname (.a_lab) to change its text? I want second statement in the changer function above to work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the pathname, remove the `$::` prefix. The prefix is used to substitute a variable value for a variable name. A pathname is a command name and should be used as it is.

Comment: You have made it really simple! Thanks.